# Difference between 粗い and 荒い

Tags: adjectives, kanji-choice

I would like to know when 粗い is used. According to the dictionary, it means "rough", but I'm not able to see the difference between 粗い and 荒い.

Is 粗い used only when a picture has bad quality? Or in what other cases can it be used?

Answer (score 8):

Both happen to be translated as "rough", but I think their antonyms will help:

- 粗い is an antonym for 細かい/なめらか/fine-grained/detailed/smooth/etc.

  > 粗い計算, 粗い見積もり, 粗いサンドペーパー, 粗く挽いたコーヒー豆
- 荒い is an antonym for 温厚/穏やか/calm/gentle/mild/etc.

  > 荒い口調, 荒い性格, 荒い天候, 荒い波, 金遣いが荒い